# An example of symmetric, coercive, discontinuous bilinear form over a Hilbert space?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, bilinear-form

Can you show me an example of symmetric, coercive and discontinuous bilinear form over a Hilbert space?

I saw some stuff here [Give an example of a discontinuous bilinear form.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110257/give-an-example-of-a-discontinuous-bilinear-form) but the forms there are not over a Hilbert space, just Banach.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it just changing here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discontinuous_linear_map in General Existence Theorem with T(e_n,e_n)=n and T(e_n,e_m)=0 when n different m and {e_i} is an orthonormal basis.